# How to use regular expression match a line that the next line is not something?

Tags: .net, regex

I am using regular expressions to search in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 (see the documentation of Visual Studio:[Use Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio)).

I have tried this:

```
\[\s*MarshalAs\s*\(\s*UnmanagedType\s*\.\s*ByValArray\s*,\s*SizeConst\s*=\s*([^\s])*\)]\s*\r?\n\s*(?!\[\s*SizeConst\s*\(\s*SizeConst\s*=\s*\1\s*\)\])
```

According to the document above:

`\r?\n` means new line.

`(?!expression)` means invalid match.

This regular expression match ***[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]*** and the new line and the next line space before ***[SizeConst(SizeConst = 15)]***, but I want match a line of ***[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]*** the next line is not ***[SizeConst(SizeConst = 15)]***.

```
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
   [SizeConst(SizeConst = 15)]
```

I want to make sure every line

***[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = `variable`)]***

that the next line is

***[SizeConst(SizeConst = `variable`)]***

The variable may be a digit or word and maybe have a dot-like 'object.member'. The variable in the first and second line must be the same.

So how can I find the line

***[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = `variable`)]***

that the next line is not

***[SizeConst(SizeConst = `variable`)]***

Comment: @wp78de The variable may be digit or word and maybe have a dot like 'object.member'. The variable in the first and second line must be same.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[MarshalAs\(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = [0-9]*\)\]\n(?!\[SizeConst\(SizeConst = [0-9]*\)\])
```

That will match the second instance below and not the first

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
[SizeConst(SizeConst = 15)]

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
[izeConst(SizeConst = 15)]
```

The magic is `(?!\[SizeConst\(SizeConst = [0-9]*\)\])`, the `(?!)` is a negative look ahead, it means only match when what's up ahead DOESN'T match what's inside `(?!)` (Conversely a positive look ahead is `(?=)`)

This site is a joy to use for regex's https://regexr.com/

Note that it will NOT work if you have `[SizeConst(SizeConst=15)]` (no spaces around the `=`) to fix that you can use

```
\[MarshalAs\(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst\s*=\s*[0-9]*\)\]\n(?!\[SizeConst\(SizeConst\s*=\s*[0-9]*\)\])
```

the `\s*` means zero or more whitespace.

Comment: I want match the second not the first. So I can find the error in my code, the first is right.

Comment: @linjie I flipped it to use negative look ahead `(?! )` instead of positive `(?= )`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
 \[MarshalAs\(UnmanagedType\.ByValArray, SizeConst = \d+\)\](?!\n\[SizeConst\(SizeConst = \d+\)\])
```

See the regex: https://regex101.com/r/9UKsmj/1

Use negative look ahead `?!` to match only  lines not followed by 
`[SizeConst(SizeConst = variable)]` where `variable` is any number.

Comment: Your solution is fine in regex101.com, but didn't work on visual studio 2017 on windows. I didn't description complete, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

`\[MarshalAs\(UnmanagedType\.ByValArray,\sSizeConst\s=\s(\d+|[\w+.]+)\)\](?!\r?\n\[SizeConst\(SizeConst = \1\)\])`

- A negativ assertion `?!` allows you to those lines that are not
  followed by a matching line as required.
- The reference to capturing group `\1` ensures the variable in line
  two is the same as in line one.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/9D6rfT/1)

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\[MarshalAs\(UnmanagedType\.ByValArray,\sSizeConst\s=\s(\d+|[\w+.]+)\)\](?!\r?\n\[SizeConst\(SizeConst = \1\)\])";
        string input = @"[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
[SizeConst(SizeConst = 15)]

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = object.member)]
[SizeConst(SizeConst = object.member)]

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
[SizeConst(SizeConst = 14)]

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
[SizeConst(SizeConst = object.member)]";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```